# Using Isolates in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to understand how I can create a background process in a Flutter Application. Basically, My understanding is that once a user has started the application, the Isolate can be created. This will allow my code to run on the background.

In the background, I want to get a list of Bluetooth enabled devices and their RSSI values within a certain radius, every 30 seconds or so.

I am aware that there are some Bluetooth libraries available for Flutter, but Time is really limited and It would be best to seek advice from experienced flutter developers.

Specifically, I would like to know the following -

1. Is using Isolates the best way to go about doing this? From my research, I understand that the user has to start the Isolate through some UI Activity?
2. Could the Isolate(Background Service) repeat every periodically to perform certain tasks?
3. I need to be able to write the data received from the Bluetooth scan to a database. I understand that the Isolate will not be the best place for this? Based on this [blog post](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124) by Ben Konyi, it is not good practice to do such tasks within an Isolate.

Comment: *"I want to get a list of Bluetooth enabled devices"* - how? you need some plugin anyway...

Comment: I was thinking of using https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue

Comment: so you have https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue#scan-for-devices - you dont need any isolate for that

Comment: I am trying to use that library in a background service(without user interaction) to do periodic work. Example - Scan Bluetooth devices, get RSSI values, Store in a DB, repeat

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I'm trying to do the exact same process.

Comment: Nothing at the moment.